# MobileFirst 7.1 connectOnStartup & WL.Client.connect different

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In MobileFirst 7.1 project, connectOnStartup property work still fine

```
var wlInitOptions = {
   connectOnStartup : true,
   ...
 }

 if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {     
    WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); }, false);
 } else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload',  function() {   
    WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); });
 }
```

Use this code and setup worklight server path & context, MobileFirst Application will check whether this application need to update.

But this property is deprecated since Worklight v6.2.

[MF7.1 info center document](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html%23init) says about this property :

> Deprecated: The connectOnStartup init option is deprecated. Worklight
>   applications by default are configured to not connect to the Worklight
>   Server. If you would like your application to connect to the Worklight
>   Server, use WL.Client.connect().

this document says we should use WL.Client.connect();

I use this API [WL.Client.connect API](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html%23connect),  and set connectOnStartup to false, simply used following code:

```
WL.Client.connect({
    onSuccess :function(){ console.log("success")},
    onFailure :function(){ console.log("Fail");},
    timeout :5000
});
```

This code works fine too.

Here is our question:

1. The different between connectOnStartup flag & WL.Client.connect
2. Can I just use connectOnStartup flag to set whether the MF 7.1 application should check update or not although it was deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not use deprecated APIs or properties, for the reason that we can decide to completely remove them at any moment, and then it'll stop working for you and you'll complain that it is not working. Don't use it.